# Autowiring Not getting disabled using xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring

Despite giving the beans, value of false to the attribute autowire-candidate, they are getting autowired. Not able to find what i am missing.

**Color.java**

```
package org.manya.autowire;

public class Color {

    private String color;

    public void setColor(String color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getColor()
    {
        return this.color;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.color;
    }
}
```

**Engine.java**

```
package org.manya.autowire;

public class Engine {
    private String engine;

    public void setEngine(String engine)
    {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public String getEngine()
    {
        return engine;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.engine;
    }
}
```

**Car.java**

```
package org.manya.autowire;

public class Car {
    private Color color;
    private Engine engine;
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        System.out.println("From the setter of Color in org.manya.innerBean.Car");
        this.color = color;
    }
    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        System.out.println("From the setter of Engine in org.manya.innerBean.Car");
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "This car has, engine : " + this.engine + ", color : " + this.color;
    }
}
```

**autowire.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="car" class="org.manya.autowire.Car" autowire="byName"
     />

    <bean name="color" class="org.manya.autowire.Color" autowire-candidate="false">
        <property name="color">
            <value>Grey</value> 
        </property> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="engine" class="org.manya.autowire.Engine" autowire-candidate="false"
    p:engine="v10"  
    />

</beans>
```

> In autowire.xml i have declared car as **autowired by name**, but both of its dependencies i have declared as **autowire-candidate as false**. So this code should have given me an Exception. But when i am running it, Car is getting instantiated. What am i missing here?

Comment: Why should it give an exception, the fact that there is nothing to auto wire doesn't automatically lead to an exception.

Comment: To disable autowire,you can put autowire="no" on bean definition or remove autowire property on bean defintion of car.

Comment: I dont want to remove autowiring. I was expecting if i have given a bean a attribute of autowire byName and i am declaring all its dependencies as autowire-candidate as false. then it should give an error as its dependencies will not get injected by the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Spring JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15072) `autowire-candidate="false"` only affects type-based autowiring attempts, not direct references by name... and not autowire="byName" either.

> While the latter may be debatable, I'm not inclined to change it at this point since `autowire="byName"` is an outdated mechanism to begin with. I'm therefore turning this into a documentation issue.

Comment: i thought it would throw any exception. i was wrong about it. but yes. now its dependencies are not getting injected by the container. thanks.